# How to load sage pay gateway in ios app?

Tags: ios, opayo

I want to know sage pay form integration in IOS with sage pay gateway load. If you have knowledge on this please let me know the procedure.

Comment: you can do this via your custom backend API. Hit sagepay2/transaction_new.php in webview and interact with response with your API. In App check URL in webview delgates and get success or failure. I implement in one of my app in same way.

Comment: sagepay2/transaction_new.php  is my custom API in which i register transaction at sagepay .